# Sed: Search for a string to find a specific line then replace different text in that line

Tags: text, awk, sed

I have a file with many different lines in it and I need a way to find specific lines:

```
user=omega group=plasma account=test jobname=STDIN queue=omega_node
```

I want to use sed to search for "account=test" then replace "group=plasma" with "group=solid". I know how to do a "sed -i" and do the replacement but I can't figure out a way to do a search then pass replacement parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a conditional substitution using this syntax:

```
sed '/account=test/s/group=plasma/group=solid/' file
```

This only performs the substitution on lines which match the pattern `account=test`.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked wonderfully, I didn't know it was called a conditional substitution. Thank you again @TomFenech!